# ResNet152 - High Training Accuracy but Failed to Classify Binary Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, vgg-net

I am working on the Skin Cancer Images available in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/fanconic/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign) for my mini-project.  I am trying to use different CNN models for comparison.  Both VGG16 and VGG19 work on the data and yield acceptable results with >90% of accuracy on training, validation data, and around 85% on testing data.

However, it appears ResNet50/152 overfit the data as it could also produce >90% accuracy on training data but fails on validation/testing data (all validation/testing images are classified as 1/0).  I have tried image augmentation and dropout but both of them don't work for me.  Appreaciate if I could get any comment on the following block of codes, thanks so much!

```
IMAGE_WIDTH = 224
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 224
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3

train_data, valid_data, train_label, valid_label = train_test_split(trainval_data, trainval_label, test_size=0.05, random_state=999)

train_label = to_categorical(train_label)
valid_label = to_categorical(valid_label)
test_label = to_categorical(test_label)

train_array = np.zeros((len(train_data), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS))
test_array = np.zeros((len(test_data), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS))
valid_array = np.zeros((len(valid_data), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS))

for i in range(len(train_data)):
    image = load_img(train_data[i], target_size=(224, 224))
    train_array[i] = img_to_array(image)

for i in range(len(test_data)):
    image = load_img(test_data[i], target_size=(224, 224))
    test_array[i] = img_to_array(image)

for i in range(len(valid_data)):
    image = load_img(valid_data[i], target_size=(224, 224))
    valid_array[i] = img_to_array(image)

train_array = train_array/255.0
test_array = test_array/255.0
valid_array = valid_array/255.0

def img_transfer(image):
    image = image - image.mean()
    return image

# data pre-processing for training
train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 20,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    fill_mode = 'nearest',
    horizontal_flip = True,
    preprocessing_function=img_transfer)

# data pre-processing for validation
validate_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 20,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    fill_mode = 'nearest',
    horizontal_flip = True,
    preprocessing_function=img_transfer)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=img_transfer)

train_datagen.fit(train_array, augment=True, seed=8021)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(train_array, train_label, shuffle=True, seed = 8021)

validate_datagen.fit(valid_array, augment=True, seed=8021)
val_generator = validate_datagen.flow(valid_array, valid_label, shuffle=True, seed = 8021)

resnet152model = ResNet152(include_top=False, classes=2, input_shape = (224,224,3))
#print(vgg16model.summary())

for layer in resnet152model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = resnet152model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

resnet152model = Model(inputs=resnet152model.input,outputs=predictions)

earlystop = EarlyStopping(patience=10)

learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', 
                                            patience=5, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.00001)

filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

callbacks_list = [earlystop, checkpoint, learning_rate_reduction]

resnet152model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history1 = resnet152model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator,
                    epochs=30, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)

Epoch 1/30
79/79 [==============================] - 65s 819ms/step - loss: 3.4226 - accuracy: 0.7673 - val_loss: 0.5739 - val_accuracy: 0.6818

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.68182, saving model to weights-improvement-01-0.68.hdf5
Epoch 2/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 559ms/step - loss: 0.7746 - accuracy: 0.8092 - val_loss: 0.3414 - val_accuracy: 0.6818

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.68182
Epoch 3/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 559ms/step - loss: 0.4426 - accuracy: 0.8407 - val_loss: 0.7188 - val_accuracy: 0.6818

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.68182
Epoch 4/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 560ms/step - loss: 0.4133 - accuracy: 0.8415 - val_loss: 0.5881 - val_accuracy: 0.6818

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.68182
Epoch 5/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 558ms/step - loss: 0.3836 - accuracy: 0.8595 - val_loss: 1.2216 - val_accuracy: 0.3182

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.68182
Epoch 6/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 558ms/step - loss: 0.3961 - accuracy: 0.8551 - val_loss: 1.0454 - val_accuracy: 0.3182

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.68182

Epoch 00006: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0005000000237487257.
Epoch 7/30
79/79 [==============================] - 44s 558ms/step - loss: 0.3074 - accuracy: 0.8719 - val_loss: 0.9247 - val_accuracy: 0.3182
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem, i.e. why VGG works while ResNet doesn't, is caused by the keras `BatchNormalization` layer. Long story in short, because of the domain gap between the ImageNet dataset and your own dataset, the pretrained BatchNormalization parameters don't reflect the actual batch statistics of your new dataset.

Therefore, here are some options:

- Option 1: fast training, but might be slightly worse performance

  - freeze all feature extraction layers of your ResNet model
  - only train your classification layer
- Option 2: slightly slow training, but might be better performance

  - build a customized ResNet -- everything is the same as the original ResNet, except for those `BatchNormalization` layers.
  - load a pretrained ResNet in this customized one
  - train the customized network instead.
  - More precisely, you should call `BatchNormalization` layer as below, where `training=False` (read the keras doc carefully, https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/)

```
f = BatchNormalization(...)(x, training=False)
```

Note: both options do one common thing -- disable the updating of the `BatchNormalization` parameters during finetuning. Test it and see whether it works.

Comment: Not sure if you are referring to the following but I’ve already set:

for layer in resnet152model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

Comment: NOTE: not sure what you did will be equivalent, but I will not be surprise if it is not. In BatchNormalization, you have both trainable parameters and non-trainable parameters. Using layer.trainable = False will surely disable the updating of trainable parameters (i.e. gamma and beta) but I don't whether it will have the same effect on the non-trainable ones (i.e. running mean and variance).